# Is there a .NET library or tool available for interacting with DITA content?

Tags: c#, dita

We are integrating documentation authored according to DITA. The [DITA Open Toolkit](http://dita.xml.org/wiki/the-dita-open-toolkit) processes all files using java whereas we are looking for a solution that allows us to work with the DITA content on the fly from a C#-based application.

Does anyone know of any .NET projects that are written to work with DITA maps and content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there are any Microsoft-made DITA libraries available for .NET.

There was a paper written for SIGDOC 2008 called "Pragmatic DITA on a budget" that refers to generating DITA content from commented C# code.  A PDF is available [here.](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1456536.1456577) This probably isn't quite what you're looking for, but it could be useful...
It might be worth getting in touch with the author about this project.

Comment: Thanks, that's really interesting!

Comment: Accepting in lieu of more specific answers, this is the best so far.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the cleanest solution in the world, but you could call the DITA Open Toolkit command line tools through `Process`.  If you do it right, you can suppress the console window and the user won't know the difference.

Comment: Yeah, I had considered that but the technical lead was not interested in installing the OT to the build environment. I'm not on this project anymore but I'm still looking for answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool like [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) to turn the java toolkit jars into .net assemblies and then use the toolkit from there.